# how to concat a constant in between the url

Tags: php

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="onboard_help_anchor" 
onclick="openHelpWindow(<%= '\'https://helpdesk.orangescrum.com/cloud/create-quick-task/#due_date\'' %>)"
title="<?php echo __("Get quick help on Due Date");?>" rel="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8FD;</i></a>
```

I want to add a constant inside the url after #due_date..

Comment: Can you try if this works: Can you try if this works: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="onboard_help_anchor" 
onclick="openHelpWindow(<%= '\'https://helpdesk.orangescrum.com/cloud/create-quick-task/#due_date' + CONSTANT + '\'' %>)"
title="<?php echo __("Get quick help on Due Date");?>" rel="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8FD;</i></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick="openHelpWindow(<%= ''https://helpdesk.orangescrum.com/cloud/create-quick-task/#due_date'' %>)"

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="onboard_help_anchor" 
onclick="openHelpWindow(<%= '\'https://helpdesk.orangescrum.com/cloud/create-quick-task/<?php echo CONSTANT;?>#due_date\'' %>)"
title="<?php echo __("Get quick help on Due Date");?>" rel="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8FD;</i></a>
```

Comment: If you are writing inside the ctp file you can simply add this way